# How to trigger a script execution after Dropbox updates a specific directory?

Tags: python, linux, bash, dropbox

I want to automate a process after Dropbox does update changes made to a directory (changes could be made in a subdirectory too).

In order for this to work the monitoring script should wait for Dropbox to report the synchronization status as done, as I do not want to start the action when only some files where updated, or to start multiple executions in parallel.

This has to work on Linux, where I do have the Dropbox headless daemon already configured to run. I also have the dropbox.py script which seems to be able to report if the syncronization was made.

```
./dropbox.py status
Up to date
```

I was considering using a cron job but I do want to minimize the delay between the moment when dropbox finishes the sync and the moment I trigger the execution. Using Cron every minute does not seem a good approach, I would prefer something that is using some kind of triggers, not a dumb polling.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what triggers are available with Dropbox.  That seems like the sort of thing you'd contact their support department about, since they are after all a commercial service.

If you find yourself stuck with polling, you could wrap your python script in a loop that checks for a state change.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

postprocess() {
  # This function contains stuff you run after sync is complete.
}

# Initialize a flag.
dirty=true

# How many seconds between checks?
interval=1

# Poll every second. You could increase this number to reduce impact.
while sleep $interval; do

  if $dirty; then
    if /path/to/dropbox.py status | grep -q 'Up to date'; then
      dirty=false
      postprocess
    else
      # Still syncing, no state change, try again in $interval seconds
      continue
    fi
  else
    if /path/to/dropbox.py status | grep -q 'Up to date'; then
      # No updates happening, no state change
      continue
    else
      dirty=true
    fi
  fi

done
```

I haven't tested this obviously, but perhaps you can adapt it to your needs.  Note that a shorter interval means that the script will more accurately detect changes, a longer one means it may miss them.  Even at a 1 second interval, I would expect the dropbox client could start and complete a change within 1 second, so you might miss things.

If you know of a way to detect a trigger, please post your code here, and you'll find a crowd of people happy to help make it work.  A question without code to debug is .. well, practically off-topic!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the **inotify** system. There's a command line tool `inotifywait`, and a python library. You can be notified of a file being created, read, closed after write, etc.

Comment: How would inotify know that the synchronization is *complete*? I thought it would only provide notification of a *change*.

Comment: I imagined that the proper solution would involve inotify. When it comes to knowing when the sync was finishes, I can check the dropbox.py response.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `fswatch`. I've used it before to do something similar. This is a line from a program I used it on.

`fswatch --print0 -e '/\.' $dir | xargs -0 -n1 ./client.py`